# how to create structured JSON from CSV in AWS Glue

Tags: python, arrays, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am able to create structured json in expected format but extra slashes appear in the JSON records and also json records shows as a string object.

Please elaborate the solution or let me know what is is missing or if any other approach exists to achieve the expected result.

**My Current Result:**

```
{
   "awsservices":[
      "{"\key":\"string_value"\, \"key":\numeric_value, "\key":\"amazon\web/services"}",
      "{"\key":\"string_value"\, \"key":\numeric_value, "\key":\"amazon\web/services"}",
      "{"\key":\"string_value"\, \"key":\numeric_value, "\key":\"amazon\web/services"}",
      "{"\key":\"string_value"\, \"key":\numeric_value, "\key":\"amazon\web/services"}"
   ]
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
   "awsservices":[
      {"key":"string_value", "key":numeric_value, "key":"amazon web services"},
      {"key":"string_value", "key":numeric_value, "key":"amazon web services"},
      {"key":"string_value", "key":numeric_value, "key":"amazon web services"},
      {"key":"string_value", "key":numeric_value, "key":"amazon\web/services"}
   ]
}
```

**My Code:**

```
SourceDataDYF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
   format_options = {"quoteChar": '"', "escaper":"", "withHeader":True, "separator":"|", "inferSchema":"false"},
   connection_type = "s3",
   format = "csv",
   connection_options = {"paths": "s3:bucket_name/csv_file_path/"], "recurse":True},
   transformation_ctx = "SourceDataDYF"
)

StageDataDF = SourceDataDYF.toDF()

print("*******************************: WRITE JSON :*******************************")

PreStageDataDF1 = StageDataDF.select(to_json(struct(*StageDataDF.columns)).alias("json")) \
   .groupBy(spark_partition_id()) \
   .agg(collect_list("json").alias("awsservices")) \
   .select(col("awsservices").cast("string")).coalesce(1)

targetDataDYF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(PreStageDataDF1,glueContext,"PreStageDataDF1")
targetDataJSON = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
   frame = targetDataDYF,
   connection_type = "s3",
   connection_options = {"path": "s3://result_bucket_name/folder_path/", "partitionKeys": []},
   format = "json",
   transformation_ctx = "targetDataJSON"
)
```

Comment: Since the the data is basically correct, except for the "values" being a list of strings rather than dicts, what happens if you don't do `.cast("string")`?

Comment: to_json should be enough and you don't need to case it to sting before writing

Comment: @JonSG, I tried with Pandas.converted logic in pandas and its working and getting expected josn format.

Answer (score 0):

I have created structured or expected format JSON using below code:

```
StageDataDF = SourceDataDYF.toDF()
StageDataDF.schema
StageDataDF.show(5)

print("**************:Converting Spark DF to pandas DF:******************")
StageDataDF1 = StageDataDF.toPandas()
print(StageDataDF1)

print("#############: Converting into Python Dictionary:#############")
StageDataDF2 = StageDataDF1.to_dict(orient = 'records')
print(StageDataDF2)

print("#############: Converting Dictionary to 2D list:#############")
StageDataDF3 =[[ rec for rec in StageDataDF2 ]]
StageDataDF4 = {"awsservices":StageDataDF3}
print(StageDataDF4)

print("#############: Converting Python Dictionary to Pandas DataFrame:#############")
StageDataDF5 = pd.DataFrame(data = StageDataDF4)
print(type(StageDataDF5))

print("#############: Converting Pandas DataFrame to Spark DF again:#############")
StageDataDF6 = spark.createDataFrame(StageDataDF5)
print(type(StageDataDF6))
StageDataDF6.show()

print("*******************************: Traget Dynamic Data Frame :*******************************")
targetDataDYF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(StageDataDF6, glueContext, "StageDataDF6").coalesce(1)
print(type(targetDataDYF))
targetDataDYF.show()

targetDataJSON = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = targetDataDYF, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket/folder/", "partitionKeys": []},format = "json",transformation_ctx = "targetDataJSON")
```

Comment: But problem is, while writing result in json format want some json values in numeric format, and not in string format.

Comment: example: Resultant Json Format:
{
 "awsservices": [
  {
   "Process": "ZCF",
   "qnty": "1",
   "DiText": "Related",
   "LastUpdtDate": "20210819180815",
   "Code": "008",
   "CvelCost": "94.9",
   "EndDate": "20140630000000",
  }
  ]
}---------------Expected Json Format:
{
 "awsservices": [
  {
   "Process": "ZCF",
   "qnty": 1,
   "DiText": "Related",
   "LastUpdtDate": 20210819180815,
   "Code": 008,
   "CvelCost": 94.9,
   "EndDate": 20140630000000,
  }
  ]
}

Comment: It would be great, if anybody help here.